# replace .0 on varchar data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-like

I have a varchar column that has numbers with .0

This column has both numeric data and non-numeric data.

I first tried to convert data type to integer, but since there is non-numeric data type, it would not let me.

How do I remove .0 (from all numbers that has .0)?

So, for example, 100.0 should be 100

I am not trying to use select, cast or truncate as I need to actually modify the existing data.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `"I have a varchar column...that has numbers"` And there's the first mistake ;)

Comment: Not necessarily.  If no math will ever be done on the numbers; varchar makes sense.  Zip code, telephone number, ssn, credit card #, I'd never store as "numeric"

Comment: `'1000.0'` should be trimmed, but what about `'1,000.0'`? `'-10.0'`? `'$1,000.0'`? When is a value sufficiently non-numeric that it shouldn't be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column has both numeric and non-numeric data it is not enough to just check if it ends with `'.0'`.
You should also check if it is a numeric value, which can be done with [`TRY_CAST()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=936d97db6485c5bffc7f38e3070e348c):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = LEFT(col, LEN(col) - 2)
WHERE col LIKE '%.0' AND TRY_CAST(col AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=936d97db6485c5bffc7f38e3070e348c).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to update your table...

- where x = your table name
- yourfieldname = the field name you need to update.

.

```
UPDATE table X 
SET yourfieldName = left(yourfieldname,len(yourieldName)-2) 
WHERE right(yourfieldName,2)='.0')
 -- or perhaps where yourfieldname like '%.0' would be faster...
```

Should: update all fields ending in .0  would need to test to see which where clause would be faster depending on indexes.  if speed is a consideration.  If not; and this is a 1 and done... does it matter?

Be sure to test on a subset/copy table!

Assumes you don't have a spaces after the .0... or any non-display characters.. If you do you'll need to trim off the spaces and replace the non-display characters with empty string ''

Comment: may need to add `and isnumeric(yourfieldname)=1` to your where clause if the column needs to be numeric to do the removal.

Comment: be careful with `ISNUMERIC`; its a legacy function that doesn't work like people think. Here's some expressions that ISNUMERIC will return a 1 for. `'.','-.','$','+'`. TRY_CAST, as forpas demonstrates, is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('100.0')
,('1001.0')
,('Not Numeric')
,('-200.05')
,('10,250.0')

Update @YourTable
   set SomeCol = format(try_convert(money,SomeCol),'#.######')
 From @YourTable
 Where try_convert(money,SomeCol) is not null
```

**The Updated Table**

```
SomeCol
100
1001
Not Numeric
-200.05
10250
```